# How to put script file in the head of view using EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs, head

I included layout to my view and also i need to make JS script to load for this view directly in the head. How to do that ?

```js
// view file
<%- layout('/layout/boilerplate.ejs') %>
<script> 
 // want to load script in the HEAD of my boilerplate file.
</script>
```

I tried to add head tag and expected it to combined with head in boiler plate but didn`t. Do not want to add to boilerplate because it be downloaded for every route then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps that needs to be followed.

1. Put your JS files in the /public folder of your project.
2. Configure the Node server to serve your Static files.
3. Use a script tag to reference your JS in your ejs file

Hope this will be helpful.
Cheers!!

Comment: It is, but i need scripts be in head of html not after closing tag body